# Two rows of buttons that are mobile responsive

Tags: button, row, responsive, center

I'm trying to create two rows of buttons, 3 on the top and 4 on the bottom to sit centred on the page

[Image showing what I am trying to do][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgVLS.jpg

I've managed to get the two rows, however when i try and centre them on the page by adding:
display: flex; justify-content: center;
I loose the gap around each of the buttons - I can't work out where to add the padding to give a consistent space between each button!

I was also hoping for the buttons to be mobile responsive and wrap on smaller screens. However I can't seem to figure this out either!

Would really appreciate any help.

```css
.jd-btn {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.jd-btn:hover,
.jd-btn:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
<a class="jd-btn">Button 1</a>
<a class="jd-btn">Product info 2</a>
<a class="jd-btn">Button 3</a><br />
</div>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
<a class="jd-btn">Account info 4</a>
<a class="jd-btn">Product info 5</a>
<a class="jd-btn">Help 6</a>
<a class="jd-btn">Button 7</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ```flex-wrap```may be what you need. [Here's a link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

Comment: Thank you - this page shows that there is only partial support for IE11 users. I know we have a high number of users using that browser. Do you know how the code will be affected?

Comment: It seems the  problem is that IE11 tries sometimes to increase the container width and not wrap flex items. To stop that, I believe you can just set a definite width to the container. Even ```100%```, I think, will work.